# How do tech-companies employ Random Forest on large data sets?

Tags: r, random-forest, bigdata

The algorithm takes quite a long time to train on large data sets with a moderate number of parameters:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37370/random-forest-computing-time-in-r

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997134/random-forest-tuning-tree-depth-and-number-of-trees

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278688/how-can-you-reduce-the-default-ntree-500-parameter-passed-to-rf-from-caret

I've been trying to run it on a ~25,000 row data set with 36 predictors and it has been using 6GB of RAM for over 2 hours.

Are there instances where this algorithm is used in production or is being run daily? If so, how does one approach re-training it or optimising it for large data sets?

Comment: **> [Online learning.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning)** You will train it once, and gradually update in production. Check this cool variant of [mondrian forests](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5234-mondrian-forests-efficient-online-random-forests.pdf).

Comment: Try setting n_jobs = -1 if you aren't already.

Answer (score 4):

For the Random Forests algorithm, the time complexity for building a complete un-pruned tree is $O(m.n\log(n))$, where $n$ is the number of records/instances and $m$ is the number of variables. The algorithm is embarrassingly parallel so in many cases companies with available resources will simply use sufficient compute nodes to enable the model to run in a time that they consider reasonable.

Comment: I don't understand the `.` in your *m.n log(n)* expression. Is it meant to be multiplication (`⋅`), or something else?

Comment: @amalloy yes, it signifies multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Random Forest is based on **bagging and voting**.

It means all the individual model has to persist to be used in prediction. Hence **increasing the count of estimators will need more RAM**.

The good news is that the same property makes it **eligible to be trained in parallel** if Cores/CPU is available. Please try that.@Brady Gilg has suggested the same.

I have tried ~10 Mn records with estimator count between 15-40 and it needed less than 30 mins. It seems your production system is very light Or something is incorrect with the E2E model.